# Problems with text in R plots and LaTeX

Tags: r, graph, plot, latex, eps

Hello stackoverflow community,

I have trouble with the interaction between text in R plots and the Latex Environment. In R, I programmed a simple distributional plot and added the percentage below a given threshold via the command `mtext(expression(paste("x% < 0 < 1-x%")), ...)` . Then the graph has been saved as eps.-figure in order to Transfer it to Latex. The latter, however, displays the `<` and `>` symbols as inverted exclamation marks (usually, the `<` are obtained by the command `\textless` outside the mathmode in Latex).

I further added some font packages in Latex and it becomes possible to type the `<` signs into the text without drawing on the math mode. In the Graphs from R, however, the inverted exclamation marks remain.

Does anybody knows how to solve this issue? Although I think that it is a general problem between the R text and Latex, please let me know if some code helps to understand the Problem.

Thank you very much for your help and suggestions.

Comment: Can you please provide a simple reproducible example of your LaTeX document and the R code you use to generate the plot? This does not need to include all details, just enough to produce the specific problem you describe.

Comment: Maybe you could use the Latex-Package `overpic`. I find it much easier and much more flexible: See here
http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/overpic/opic-rel.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a general issue in the communication between R and LaTeX, although I agree it can be tricky. I wasn't able to reproduce the behavior you described using what I normally do to create graphics for TeX-documents.

Maybe this setup can also solve the problem you describe. Below is an example to print the said expression using `Cairo` and PDF graphics.

R-script:

```
library(Cairo)

Cairo(file="pic", type="pdf", dpi=100)
  x <- y <- 1:5
  plot(x,y)
  mtext(expression(paste("x% < 0 < 1-x%")))
dev.off()
```

TeX-file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,paper=a4]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[tbp]
  \includegraphics{pic.pdf}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The resulting PDF that is compiled using `pdflatex` appears to show the expression correctly. A quick screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]